# how to change kernel zImage for raspberry pi

Tags: kernel

I'm using yocto to build linux for rpi2 and I don't want flashing full sdimg to sdcard. I just want replace kernel image into rpi2 and don't want change rootfs already in sdcard. How I can do that?

I tried delete /boot/zImage in sdcard but I still boot fine and don't have anything happen.

Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

Hy!
You tired  out this: you write in the config.txt this: "kernel = $your kernel name". Already it helped once for me.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here. Could you please elaborate a little more what needs to be done - certainly it is not all settled just by writing one line in the config?